# Delete opening and closing tag in web-mode

Tags: html, web-mode

Is there a way to delete opening and closing html tags in `web-mode`? I have tried using `sgml-delete-tag` from within `web-mode` but can't get it to work properly (I get an error message `sgml-lexical-context: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`). Is there a way to delete matching tags in `web-mode`?

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `emacs -Q` with web-mode enabled?

Comment: @ReneFroger Yes, same issue. It works if I switch the major mode to `sgml-mode`, but not in `web-mode`

Comment: Could you post it on the https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode issue tracker, with steps to reproduce this issue with an empty Emacs configuration?

Comment: I posted a  smilair issue earlier: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/460